# "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller

This is the list class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "list")
public class List extends AbstractEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private Date date;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Following is the execution class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXECUTION")
public class Execution extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = List.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "list_id")
    private List list;

    @Column(name = "date")
    @NotNull
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private Date date;
}
```

Following is the controller method to delete list

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void deleteList(@PathVariable("id") Long listId) {
    List list = listRepository.findOne(listId);

    listRepository.delete(listId);
}
```

While I execute the above code I get the following error

```
: ERROR: update or delete on table "list" violates foreign key constraint "fkmnja1nmiq9v42f0ojydccxf20" on table "execution"
```

Detail: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "execution".

How can I delete the execution table with list id's before deleting the list table with a particular id?

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: There is no jpa relationship between Execution and List - add a relationship and it will delete

Comment: There is a ManyToOne relationship between execution and list. I'm relatively new to this. Could you help me out in what needs to be done

Comment: you would need a reverse relationship on list->execution to delete. as a test delete an execution to see what i mean(that should delete list)

Comment: what is your jpa or hibernate version

Comment: Do post your `AbstractEntity` class as well.

Answer (score 1):

Define cascade behavior on your relationship,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXECUTION")
public class Execution extends AbstractEntity {
    //add cascade , so on delete of list all the execution will also be removed
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = List.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "list_id")
    private List list;

    @Column(name = "date")
    @NotNull
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private Date date;
}
```